# JavaFX on Android 2.2 - Invalid Package

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

When I try to run JavaFX app on on Android, it wont install, it says "invalid package". Is Android 2.2 not supported?

Comment: Just curious, why Android 2.2?

Comment: I dont have any phone. I tried emulator, but I always got black screen.

Comment: How did you get Android 2.2 working then?

Comment: I tried the Ensemble8 created by Johan Vos. It got black screen on the Emulator, when I tried to install it in Android 2.2, it says "Invalid Package".

Answer (score 1):

No Android isn't supported, but you can find a porting community here:

https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Home